# I'm having difficulty appending a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I originally couldn't think of a way to append an additional class to an li element which had a class that other li elements had. I wanted to only add a class to that specific li element that I clicked a select button on and the solution was "On the click of the button, you can use .closest() to find the ancestor li element". The solution was a jquery solution and it works fine but now I'm having an additional problem. First, here's what I originally posted and the solution I was given along with the fiddle and then I will explain what my new problem is and would appreciate the help. So my original post:

"Ok so my script allows me to input text in a textarea element and add it to a li element within an ordered list with the id "Glist". Not only is text added to each li I add to the ordered list, but the additional things below are added as well and they all just display additional images using CSS. One of the classes, "Selimg" displays a sprite image of a button that says "select". Now each li element I add to my ol has all of the elements below as well as the classes. So each li element will have a div with a "Selimg" class that displays an image of a button that says select for example. When I click this div with the class Selimg, a new class named "Selected" will be added to the div which will change the background color of the li to indicate that it has been selected. The problem is, I want to only add the "Selected" class to the div with the Selimg class that I've clicked, not all li elements with "Selimg" classes. How can I do that with an onclick event handler or any other way using js or jquery? Here's the html:

```
<ol id="GList">
   <li class="MyList">
      <p class="bulletp"></p>
      <!--This Selimg class displays an image of a button that says select-->
      <div class="Selimg"></div>
      <!--When a user presses this select button, I want to append a class only to the specific li element the user has pressed the select button on. -->
      <div class="edit1"></div>
      <div class="Del"></div>
      <div class="progress"></div>
      <div class="ShowMore"></div>
      <div class="CheckedGoal"></div>
      <div class="PCompetePercent"></div>
      <div class="ShowMoreBlock"></div>
      <div class="goalTxt"></div>
   </li>
</ol>

The solution I was given: 

"On the click of the button, you can use .closest() to find the ancestor li element"

$('.Selimg').click( function() {
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('someclasss')
   //or $(this).parent().addClass('someclasss') since the li is the parent of the button
})
```

here's the fiddle demonstrating the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fSMDv/2/

And now for the new issue. For some reason, the jquery solution was not working on it's own. Somehow, the jquery code above only worked when I placed it into a js function like this:

```
<script>
  function runSel() {
     var $li = $('.Selimg').closest('li').addClass('liselected');
     $li.siblings().removeClass('liselected');
  }
</script>
```

I also have a function that's called whenever I want to add another item to the list.

```
//This is only the part of the code that creates the div that I style to look like and be used as a button that says select. There's more code that also creates the li element itself and a few additional things but all for design. Nothing important.

var Selimg = document.createElement('div'); 
Selimg.setAttribute("class", "Selimg");
Selimg.setAttribute("onclick", "runSel();");
entry.appendChild(Selimg);
```

What this does is, create the div with the class "Selimg" which will be an image of a select button added to my list item and then it's given the onclick attribute that calls the runSel() function above as you can see. It works. However it only works once. The fiddle example demonstrates what I'm looking for. So now, when I add an item to the list, and click the select button on it, the function "runSel" is called which adds a class called "liselected" and liselected just changes the background color because the rules for each property in the css, have "!important" so the background color overrides the current one. It works, but like I said it only works once. After I add another item, and press the Select button on that one (which is made from the styles from the Selimg class), the liselected class is removed from the other li element yet the second li element that I just clicked the select button on, only causes the liselected class to be removed from the first but it's not added after that to the second li item, the current one. So, when i add multiple li, they will contain things like text and a div styled to look like a button that says "select" and so when I click "select" on an li, I want then for that specific li to have the liselected class appended and when I select the "select" button on another li, I want the class liselected to be removed from the other li element it was on and added to that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery solution will work fine... the problem is you are dealing with dynamically created elements... so need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.Selimg',  function() {
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('someclasss')
   //or $(this).parent().addClass('someclasss') since the li is the parent of the button
})
```

Also from what I understand you have not added the script in a dom ready handler

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V8dDU/)

Comment: ahhh, we meet again Arun.  I suppose I misunderstood, definitely delegation if it's being added dynamically.

Comment: @SolomonClosson hi again... the previous code should have worked if OP has added it in dom ready handler I think...

Comment: @ArunPJohny the only issue I'm having is removing the class from other li elements once I select one. Right now, I press select button for first li element and class is added, then I add second li element and press select and class is not removed from first element, it stays and of course is also added to second element I pressed the select button on and 3rd etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have written a book for such a small issue.  I mean, I got tired of reading what you wrote after the first 30 lines of not getting to the point of the question.

Use:  `$(this).parent('li').addClass("...")` instead.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSMDv/4/)

Comment: using that line of code, I'm able to add the class to various li elements upon clicking the select button I have but it does not remove the classes from the other li elements which is what I want.

Comment: @Brandon see the attached fiddle in my answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've checked it. It looks identical to the previous fiddle.